# How can I create an Image viewer like this in sencha touch?

Tags: image, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I need to create an image viewer like this in sencha touch. It should show the thumbnails of images. Clicking thumbnails should show the enlarged image. I'm a newbie in sencha touch. Please help me. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such standard gallery plugin so you have to do it yourself. You can try this:

Create a container with 2 panels in `vbox` layout, bigger top panel will have an `image` and lower panel will be a horizontal `list`. on `itemtap` of any list item, you can change `src` attribute of `image`. You can create this simple list by loading data from server using store which provides both thumbnail & big image url.

I haven't tested it but this should be something like this:

```
{
    xtype : 'panel',
    layout : 'vbox',
    items : [{
        xtype : 'panel',
        flex : 5,
        items : [{
            xtype : 'image',
            id : 'myImg',
            src : 'http://xyz.com/asdf.jpg'
        }]
    },{
        xtype : 'panel',
        items : [{
            xtype : 'list',
            listeners: {
            itemtap: function(list, index, item, rec) {
                Ext.getCmp("myImg").setSrc(rec.get('bigImgUrl'));
            }
        }
        }]
    }]
}
```